# Java HTML 5 validation with XSD / trang HTML 5 Relax NG to XSD conversion

Tags: java, html, validation, xsd, relaxng

My goal is to do standalone HTML 5 Markup validation with an XSD schema in java.

In the following I describe my approach. 
Any help is appreciated -- also if there is an alternative or better way to do this.

The [WHATTF](http://whattf.org) published a [Relax NG / Schematron schema for HTML 5](http://syntax.whattf.org).

Trang [3], is an open-source converter for different XML schema languages and should be able to convert from Relax NG to XSD. With the WHATTF schema, a trang converter call can be made as follows:

```
$ java -jar ./trang.jar ./whattf/syntax/relaxng/html5.rnc html5.xsd
```

However, trang produces many of the following wanrnings on incorrect type conversion:

```
whattf/syntax/relaxng/applications.rnc:265:51: warning: cannot convert datatype library "http://whattf.org/datatype-draft"; using datatype "string"
[...]
```

I think for trang to be working, one needs to pass pluggable-datatypes [4] to jing. Jing [5] 
is a Relax NG validator and I think it used by trang.

In the whattf/syntax/relaxng/datatype folder a java implementation for these pluggable-datatypes is provided. Thus I created a html5-datatypes.jar and added it to trangs classpath as follows:

```
$ java -cp ./html5-datatypes.jar  -jar ./trang.jar ./whattf/syntax/relaxng/html5.rnc html5.xsd
```

However, this results in the same errors.

Beyond that, using the created XSD files with the `javax.xml.validation.Validator` as follows:

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema( new File("html5.xsd") );
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate( new StreamSource( new File("example.html") ) );
```

produces an exception:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cos-element-consistent: Error for type 'time.inner'. Multiple elements with name 'script', with different types, appear in the model group.
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XSConstraints.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XSConstraints.fullSchemaChecking(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:594)
at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:610)
```

[3] thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html

[4] thaiopensource.com/relaxng/pluggable-datatypes.html

[5] thaiopensource.com/relaxng/jing.html

Comment: Why do you want to convert the schema? Wouldn't it be easier to validate against the RELAXNG schema using Jing?

Comment: I need to add some additional schema elements to the XSD, which should be validated as well.

But you are right, an easier way might be adding them to the Relax NG schema directly and then use jing, instead of doing a detour over XSD.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be some XHTML 5 XSDs around in the Web. For instance, there was an open-source XHTML 5 Schema at: http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/download.shtml

Answer (score 1):

From section 8.2 of the html5 spec

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/parsing.html

> While the HTML syntax described in this specification bears a close
>   resemblance to SGML and XML, it is a separate language with its own
>   parsing rules.
>
> Some earlier versions of HTML (in particular from HTML2 to HTML4) were
>   based on SGML and used SGML parsing rules. However, few (if any) web
>   browsers ever implemented true SGML parsing for HTML documents; the
>   only user agents to strictly handle HTML as an SGML application have
>   historically been validators. The resulting confusion — with
>   validators claiming documents to have one representation while widely
>   deployed Web browsers interoperably implemented a different
>   representation — has wasted decades of productivity. This version of
>   HTML thus returns to a non-SGML basis.
>
> Authors interested in using SGML tools in their authoring pipeline are
>   encouraged to use XML tools and the XML serialization of HTML.

Thus, unless you are writing xml formed html5, you cannot use XSD to validate html5.